# Accuracy of torque specs?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, power-electronics

I am working on a project and I am defining the torque specs. I used the initial torque spec as a baseline and then went out on the floor and tested it using multiple torque wrenches.

The components I am testing are [thyristor/diode modules](http://www.semikron.com/download/assets/gecont/325.pdf).

It calls for 45 in.lb to heatsink and 26 in.lb to terminals. Even backing off with the the 15% allowable tolerance, I am below the low end of 38 in.lb to the sink and it feels like its about to shear. I am encountering this with all the components I am testing.

### Question

Are the torque values I found through empirical testing sufficient? Should I be confident in applying them to a standard?

Also, I am assuming the quality of screw, type of material the sink is made out of, all effect how much torque should be applied?

Comment: I believe that setting these specs correctly requires (among other things) a pretty good idea of the friction between the two surfaces being clamped. That having been said, I'd actually expect that the clamping in this case is to produce a good thermal interface between the component and heat sink, rather than resisting load. What are the requirements?

Comment: I am just referring to torque specifications. I don't care what a data sheet says, if I know that a screw will shear if the recommended torque is applied, then that is not a good value. Requirements: do not break the semiconductor.

Comment: I think OP is asking "since the numbers in the datasheet don't make sense if used in actual assembly, is it okay for me to ignore them? And if so, is there some other set of numbers I should use?"